# Passing POST Data to PHP via JS fails

Tags: php, javascript, post

First time I've added something huge, mixing JS, PHP, THREE and lot of other stuff. This is what I've tried.

When somebody clicks on the THREE.js scene onto a human body, selects parts of the human body and javascript then adds this to a  from which I want to save the selected things into database using PHP / MySQL.

The THREE.js scene works, I can select / unselect things and the generated dynamic HTML Output works to. For example I get a form generated like this:

```
<canvas width="1680" height="949"></canvas>
<div id="Description">Will be added to database:</div>
<form id="BodyParts" method="POST" action="index.php?s=cinput">
    <input type="checkbox" id="leg_right" name="leg_right" disabled="" value="leg_right">
    <div id="leg_right_Description">Rechtes Bein</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="leg_left" name="leg_left" disabled="" value="leg_left">
    <div id="leg_left_Description">Linkes Bein</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="torso_top" name="torso_top" disabled="" value="torso_top">
    <div id="torso_top_Description">Obertorso</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Speichern" id="Submit">
</form>
```

So, after clicking onto the submit Button I am just using var_dump($_POST); on my receiving cinput.php file. But it gives out an empty array. However when trying to reload the site Chrome tells me that some data has been sent and I need to verify it again. You know what I mean. How the heck does this generated HTML Form above not work and not send POST data which I can use in PHP?

Comment: How about posting some readable code instead of a single line?

Comment: @ Styphon: Because there is really nothing to post. The Code above is an automatic generated Form from my JS / THREE.js scene where i click onto. It's basically just the submitted form() and the receiving file using var_dump($_POST); There is nothing more to post!

Comment: That doesn't stop you from going in and formatting it so it's readable....

Comment: @Shiuyin: styphon is saying you should format the code. Not everyone has a monitor 10 miles wide so they can see the SINGLE line of code you posted. At least take the time to properly format it, with line breaks, putting each tag on a separate line, with proper indentation, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the `disabled` attribute in all of your input fields. The mere PRESENCE of this attribute, even if its value is empty (`""`) causes the field to get disabled. Disabled fields do **NOT** get submitted with the rest of the form. Since your entire form has nothing but disabled inputs, you submit nothing at all.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" value="foo" disabled="" />
<input type="text" value="bar" disabled="false" />
<input type="text" value="baz" disabled="disabled" />
```

all three of these inputs are disabled, even though by "human" logic, you'd expect only the last one to actually be disabled.

Your submit button is NOT disabled, but since there's no `name` attribute, it also doesn't submit anything to the form.

Comment: Huh? I added them because i wanted to set those checkboxes on "readonly". So as you said "disabled" is not like "readonly". Pfff. Thanks!

Comment: disabled turns them into basically window decoration. they look like input elements, but don't ACT like input elements. readonly leaves them enabled, but unchangeable.

Comment: Hm, but when i use JS now to set input.readonly = true; I can still change the value's of the checkboxes (i can select / deselect). Why?